# Wildfly 10 CLI security domain configuration

Tags: configuration, command-line-interface, wildfly

Right now our configuration of wildfly and the configuration.xml is done by a dozen of cmd scripts which call each other and so on. So pretty straight its annoying as hell.

Now I want to get rid of all that by writing a cli script which will do all the configuration as needed, but right at the beginning I am already stuck.

I simply want to add this layout of the xml over CLI:

```
    <security-realm name="ssl-realm">
        <server-identities>
            <ssl>
                <keystore path="server.keystore" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="password" alias="server" key-password="password"/>
            </ssl>
        </server-identities>
    </security-realm>
```

So entering `/core-service=management/security-realm=ssl-realm/:add` will add the security realm. When I now want to add the inner part with commands like this:

```
/core-service=management/security-realm=ssl-realm/:write-attribute(name=server-identity,value=ssl)

/core-service=management/security-realm=ssl-realm/server-identity=ssl/:add
```

I get the message

```
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => "WFLYCTL0201: Unknown attribute 'server-identity'",
    "rolled-back" => true
}
```

and

```
null
```

when trying to add the server identity directly with the security realm like this:

```
/core-service=management/security-realm=ssl-realm/server-identity=ssl/:add
```

I get the error:

```
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => "WFLYCTL0175: Resource [
    (\"core-service\" => \"management\"),
    (\"security-realm\" => \"ssl-realm\")
] does not exist; a resource at address [
    (\"core-service\" => \"management\"),
    (\"security-realm\" => \"ssl-realm\"),
    (\"server-identity\" => \"ssl\")
] cannot be created until all ancestor resources have been added",
    "rolled-back" => true
}
```

Asking google or the wildfly doc didn't really help. So if someone knows how to do it I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try with these commands:

```
/core-service=management/security-realm=ssl-realm:add()
/core-service=management/security-realm=ssl-realm/server-identity=ssl:add(alias=value,keystore-relative-to=jboss.standalone.config.dir,keystore-password=abc,keystore-path=abc.jks)
```

Answer (score 0):

The same error applies also to **database** configuration:

```
/subsystem=security/security-domain=testDB:add

/subsystem=security/security-domain=testDB/authentication=classic:add

/subsystem=security/security-domain=testDB/authentication=classic/login-module=Database:add(code=Database,flag=required,module-options=[("dsJndiName"=>"java:/MyDatabaseDS"),("principalsQuery"=>"select passwd from Users where username=?"),("rolesQuery"=>"select role, 'Roles' from UserRoles where username=?")])

reload
```

Source: [Configuring a Security Domain to use the Database Login Module](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html-single/how_to_configure_identity_management/#configuring_a_security_domain_to_use_a_database)